# How to etch images on a person's skin like a tattoo using unity and augmented reality?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm trying to work on a project in Unity that uses augmented reality to make images be tattooed on a person's skin. I have searched for options but have not found anything that is appropriate for the project. Only placing 3D objects on a object, but not making it looked like the image is tattooed. I know that this is possible as I have encountered an app that does this exactly. What I like to know is how to do this. Can someone help please? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have figured out how to track the person or parts of the person using some AR SDK the second part, overlaying the tattoo should be fairly simple. If you can get a position and a normal for the tracked surface, e.g. an arm or a hand, just place a plane there and use a shader that can display transparency and use a texture where only the tattoo parts are opaque and the rest is transparent. If you would like to get an even better effect you might look into writing a simple shader that blends the texture with the underlying image of the real world.

Comment: You could try [this](https://hololens.reality.news/how-to/add-full-body-motion-tracking-hololens-with-kinect-0174419/) or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/spatial-mapping-in-unity) or something similar .. however let me tell you .. it is very difficult / maybe not possible at all

Comment: Hi sir, I don't know if the first link is related to the project since it focuses more on motion tracking. Also, I think both links need the device HoloLens? Or am I wrong. Our project will not be using any hardware, just a mobile phone. Android particularly.

Comment: yeah you didn't specify further. You maybe can to a ceratin level with e.g. Kinect ... but using only Android and the 2D camera I fear it's quite close to impossible

Comment: Hmm really. As I have said in the post, I have already found an app that is like what I need. The app is ink hunter if you would like to see it for yourself. But how sad though if it's that difficult :(

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tattoo.inkhunter&hl=en_US this is the app. can maybe someone lead me into something that might make me create something like this? thank you so much, i'll greatly appreciate it.